# How to include Google RECAPTCHA 2 in php whitelist of form inputs

Tags: php, html, forms, recaptcha

I have a form that I decided to include Google recaptcha as an added measure of security.
When I added the recaptcha it triggers an error because the recaptcha is not whitelisted.
I read that HTML5 does not allow assigning the name attribute to div. i.e. `<div name="myName"></div>.`
Against convention, I tried adding a name attribute to the recaptcha div and adding that name to the whitelist. That approach failed.
There is an iframe within the recaptcha div that has the name attribute. I tried using the iframe name in the whitelist. That approach also failed.
There is a hidden input that has an id="recaptcha-token". I added 'recaptcha-token' to the whitelist. This approach also failed.
The hidden input is generated by the recaptcha api, so I don't think I have a means of assigning a name attribute to this input.
Does anyone have a workaround or suggestion ?

Note: form validation and whitelist all worked as expected prior to adding recaptcha.

Recaptcha works as expected if I eliminate the whitelisting of the form inputs.

This is the div within the form﻿.

```
<﻿div clas﻿s="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php print $public_key;?>"></div>
  </div>﻿
</div>
```

There is a hidden input within the form that contains a token. This input & token are completely separate of the Google Recaptcha. However this token must be verified before the form inputs are compared to the $whitelist.

Here are the code blocks:

```
function verifyFormToken($form) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION[$form.'_token'])) { 
        $errors[]= "Session not set and no token";
        return false;
    }else{
        //echo 'Session token is set.'.'</br>';
    }   

    if(!isset($_POST['token'])) {
        $errors[]= 'No form token was sent!'.'</br>';
        return false;
    }

    if ($_SESSION[$form.'_token'] !== $_POST['token']) {
        $errors[]= 'tokens don\'t match!'.'</br>';
        return false;
        die();
    }else{
        //echo 'Tokens match. Good to go.'.'</br>';
        return true;
    }   
}

    // VERIFY LEGITIMACY OF TOKEN
if (verifyFormToken('form1')) {
    // Build a whitelist of form inputs
    $whitelist = array('token','req-fName','req-lName','req-email','req-phone','req-address','req-city','req-   state','req-zip','req-message','req_method','req-dateDepart','req-dateReturn','recaptcha-token','submit');

    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$item) {
        if (!in_array($key, $whitelist)) {
            writeLog('Unknown form fields');
            die('Hack-Attempt detected. Only the fields originally included in the form are allowed!');
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer came from phpbuilder.com 
Turns out that I needed to include "**g-recaptcha-response**" in the whitelist. Hope this helps anyone else facing this issue.